# pointers cant read the correct elements in array

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointers in C, and I can't figure out how it works.
Below is the code:

```
// ptr points to an array of 2 ints
int (*ptr)[2];
int torf[2][2] = {12, 14, 16};
ptr = torf;

int (*ptr_2)[2];
int torf_2[2][2] = { {12}, {14, 16}};
ptr_2 = torf_2;
  
printf("%d %d\n", **ptr, **(ptr + 2));
printf("%d %d\n", **ptr_2, **(ptr_2 + 2));
```

The answer I want should be:

```
12 16
12 14
```

But actually I got on my PC:

```
12 6422000
12 12
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There should be several relevant warnings from your compiler. If your compiler isn’t giving you any warnings, you should look up how to turn them on.

Comment: Remember that for any pointer or array `ptr` and index `i` the expression `*(ptr + i)` is equal to `ptr[i]`. That means `**(ptr + 2)` in your code is equal to `*ptr[2]`, which is out of bounds.

Comment: The problem is `**(ptr + 2)` - who'd know what it means. Just use the bracket notation with pointers. That stands for `*ptr[2]` which is much easier to make sense of.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
// ptr points to an array of 2 ints
int(*ptr)[2];
int torf[2][2] = { 12, 14, 16 };
ptr = torf;

int(*ptr_2)[2];
int torf_2[2][2] = { {12}, {14, 16} };
ptr_2 = torf_2;

printf("%d %d\n", **ptr, **(ptr + 1));
printf("%d %d\n", **ptr_2, **(ptr_2+1));
```

when you use pointers it is like the indexes of the array it begin from 0;

good work

Answer (score 2):

If you add these lines to the end of your program:

```
printf("%p: %p %p\n", ptr, ptr+1, ptr+2);
printf("%p: %p %p\n", *ptr, *ptr+1, *ptr+2);
printf("%p: %p %p\n", **ptr, **ptr+1, **ptr+2);
```

You will note that in the first case, the numbers increase by 8, which could either be the size of a pointer or two ints.   Same goes for the second, but the third increases by the size of an int; so that is good.

So, to disambiguate 2 ints or 1 address, lets do a s/2/3/g.
Now, we see the first case the increment is now 12 ( = 3 * 4 ).
Your second case ( *ptr + i ) increments by 4, so is the address of successive ints
Your third case is the integer values themselves.

Where did it get confusing?   Quick checklist:

1. When you are trying to workout pointer / indexing problems, use unique values as much as possible.
2. Pay attention when the compiler warns you.   Eventually you will know to ignore "format '%p' expects argument ... ", but it takes time to build the confidence.
3. There is a handy program, cdecl, which converts C type expressions into something english like.
4. In *virtually all* C implementations, `int x[2][2], y[4];` have the same layout; that is, C multi-dimensional arrays are just an overlay of a single dimension array, with the arithmetic cleverly hidden.   For this reason, definitions like `int (*p)[2];` are rare and rarely useful.
   If you must go down this road, it is likely better to do something like:

   typedef int pair[2];
   pair torf[2] = { { 0, 1 }, { 2, 3 }};
   pair *ptr = torf;

if nothing else, somebody has a chance to understand it...